# How to create a map in map efficiently in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I always use multilevel map in c++, such as `map<int,map<int,map<int,int>>>`,but I can not find a very efficient way to update it or create it. Suppose I want to insert a point(1,2) into a map which is used to count the points, I will do the following:

```
map<int,map<int,int>> totalmap;
if (totalmap.find(1)==totalmap.end()){
    map<int,int> map1;
    map1[2]=1;
    totalmap[1]=map1;
}
else{
    auto& map1 = totalmap[1];
    if (map1.find(2)==map1.end())
        map1[2]=1;
    else
        map1[2]++;
}
```

I have to code too much when I need to create a 3 or 4 level map. I think there must be some better method than this. The only way I can figure out is to use multimap to combine all the key as one , but some times I really need to query the key one by one.

Comment: Are you talking of efficiency of writing code or run time efficiency?

Comment: `totalmap[1][2]++;` appears equivalent to your whole fragment.

Comment: For counting points, is there a reason not to prefer map<tuple<int,int>,int> to map<int,map<int,int>>?

Comment: Thank both of you! It seems the map can be initialized or queried directly like map[1][2]......I have tried this way long time a ago ,and  somehow it did not work. Finally,I can use it in a simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `operator[]` of the `std::map` (and like container, set, multimap, etc...) work as follow:

- If the `key` parameter is not in the container, a `value` default constructed is added with that `key` to the `map` (if is a `set`, the key is added) and returned.
- If the `key` parameter is in the container the `value` is returned.

As @IgorTandetnik recommend if you like to add (eg: a counter as the info of the two level `map`) the code totalmap[1][2]++ would work.

1. `totalmap[1]` create a new element in the `map` (key: 1, value: `map<int, int>{}`, default constructed, empty) and returned.
2. `totalmap[1][2]` create a new element in the `inner map` (key: 2 value: 0) and returned.
3. `totalmap[1][2]++` increment the returned value of the `inner map`